# missing dependent for taglib in jboss eap 6 while deploying application jstl jar

Tags: jboss

I am deploying my application on jboss eap 6. I have included the module.xml containing jstl1.2.jar in jboss-deployment-structure.xml. Please help.

```
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Test.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.s
    tandard.tag.common.xml.SetTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.web.de
    ployment.default-host./Test, service jboss.deployment.unit."Test.war".deploy
    mentCompleteService]
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Test.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.s
    tandard.tag.common.xml.WhenTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.web.d
    eployment.default-host./Test, service jboss.deployment.unit."Test.war".deplo
    ymentCompleteService]
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Test.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.s
    tandard.tag.el.core.ForEachTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.web.d
    eployment.default-host./Test, service jboss.deployment.unit."Test.war".deplo
    ymentCompleteService]
          service jboss.deployment.unit."Test.war".component."org.apache.taglibs.s
    tandard.tag.el.core.ForTokensTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.web
    .deployment.default-host./Test, service jboss.deployment.unit."Test.war".dep
    loymentCompleteService]
```

Comment: new missing/unsatisfied dependencies jboss jstl

Answer (score 0):

JSTL is provided to applications automatically in EAP 6. You don't need to specify any dependency.